# Should I wrap calls to Debugger.Log() in #if (DEBUG)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, logging, compiler-optimization

Is it necessary to wrap calls to `Debugger.Log()` in the `#if (DEBUG)` preprocessor directive for the purpose of code optimization, or will the C# compiler still produce optimized code when building the `RELEASE` configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not **any** kind of optimization on *this* call in *RELEASE* mode.

The call is present in `IL`. The only difference is that it has no any effect if there is not a *DEBUGGER* present.

From documentation [Debugger.Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.log.aspx):

> If there is no debugger attached, this method has no effect.

I would suggest to measure your app's performance and after that choose the steps to follow.

If there is no significant difference (from your app's point of view), I would leave that log as is.

In this way, in the moment of need, you can attach to your app with debugger and get messages you might need from the log, as `Debugger.Log` would work at *that* point.

Answer (score 1):

This is the declaration for Debugger.Log(), as retrieved from the Reference Source:

```
// Posts a message for the attached debugger.  If there is no
// debugger attached, has no effect.  The debugger may or may not
// report the message depending on its settings.
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static extern void Log(int level, String category, String message);
```

Note that there's no [Conditional] attribute on the method and that it carries the [MethodImplAtttribute] attribute.  Which means that the method is actually implemented in the CLR, written in C++ code.

So the method call *will* be made, regardless of the configuration.  You can find the implementation of the method from the SSCLI20 source distribution, clr/src/vm/debugdebugger.cpp.  It uses OutputDebugString(), a winapi function that displays strings in the debugger, if one is attached.  Or in a utility like SysInternals' DbgView.exe.  If neither is present then the api call just doesn't do anything and quickly returns.  You only pay for the function call overhead, a handful of nanoseconds.

There isn't anything decent to optimize about the method call, it will perform the same way whether you build the Debug or the Release configuration.  Having access to debug info in the Release build could certainly be handy, it is up to you to decide whether that's a feature you want to turn off.  Whether those nanoseconds have an observable affect on your program is hard to tell.  Measure, don't assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

A quick test of the following code (.NET 4, Release, Any CPU)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    #if (DEBUG)
        Debugger.Log(0, "category", "msg");
    #endif
    }
}
```

produces this IL

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ret 
}
```

As you can see there is NO call to the `Debugger.Log`.